# Error while running configure on nxlogs build

Tags: c++, c, mingw, msys

I'm attempting to build nxlog with some updated libraries:

```
Latest APR (1.5.2)
Non-Heartbleed vulnerable OpenSSL sources
PCRE 8.37
Zlib 1.2.8
```

After building all the dependencies I'm a little stuck on getting nxlogs to build, specifically I'm stuck on the step where I run ./configure

At first it couldn't find apr-1-config, so I added /local/apr/bin to the path.

Then it couldn't fine libapr-1 so I added /local/apr/lib to the path, this is where the problems started. When APR built there wasn't a "libapr-1" file in /local/apr/lib, only libapr-1.a, libapr-1.la, libapr-1.dll.a.

Did I build APR incorrectly?

I'm trying to build this on windows

List of steps to get where I am:

1. Install MINGW using MinGW Installation Manager

Add packages:

```
mingw-developer-toolkit
mingw-base
mingw-expat bin
mingw32-libexpat dev
msys-libopenssl dev
msys-automake
msys-autoconf
```

Setup msys fstab (c:/mingw     /mingw)

2. Install Python (2.5)
3. Add Python and mingw to system path (C:\Python25;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin)
4. Get and build APR source (I could not get APR iconv to compile)

Download:

```
http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.11.tar.gz
http://mirror.nexcess.net/apache//apr/apr-1.5.2-win32-src.zip
http://mirror.nexcess.net/apache//apr/apr-util-1.5.4-win32-src.zip
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcre/files/pcre/8.37/pcre-8.37.zip/download
http://zlib.net/zlib128.zip
```

Build:

```
Extract all files to c:\mingw\msys\1.0\src
Compile libiconv
    cd libiconv-1.11

    ./configure CFLAGS="-O2 -s -mms-bitfields -march=i686" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -s -mms-bitfields -march=i686"

    make && make install
Compile APR
    cd apr
    ./buildconf

    ./configure CFLAGS="-O0 -s -mms-bitfields -march=i686" CXXFLAGS="-O0 -s -mms-bitfields -march=i686"

    make && make install
    cd ..
Compile APR-UTIL
    cd apr-util-1.5.4
    ./buildconf --with-apr=/usr/src/apr-1.5.2

    ./configure CFLAGS="-O2 -s -mms-bitfields -march=i686" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -s -mms-bitfields -march=i686" --with-apr=/usr/src/apr-1.5.2

    make && make install
    cd ..
Compile PCRE
    cd pcre-.37
    ./configure
    make && make install
    (make threw an error corrected with make clean, autoconf -i --force, started back at step 1)
    cd ..
Compile ZLIB
    cd zlib-1.2.8
    make -f win32/Makefile.gcc
Compile nxlog
    cd nxlog-ce-2.8.1248
    ./configure
```

This is where the problems began. First it couldn't find apr-1-config.

Fixed by adding /local/apr/bin to path.

Now it can't find libapr-1, adding /local/apr/lib to the path doesn't help. There is no libapr-1 file in the MinGW directory tree; thought I do see libapr-1.a libapr-1.la libapr.dll.a. Ideas? I assume this is supposed to be a script file to respond to queries about the library's interfaces?

Comment: Get on the nxlog irc or the mailing list and point them to this question, they should know how to fix your problem.

Comment: IRC met me with crickets (no response), so far the same with the mail list.